# _blank is opened in new window on key press event - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-hooks, keyboard-events

i want to open a tab when i press shift +enter on my react Application

so I've written the logic like this

```
function Apps() {
 const onKeyPressEventHandler = React.useCallback((event) => {
  if (event?.key === 'Enter' && event.shiftKey) {
   window.open('https://www.google.com/','_blank')
   return;
  }
 }, []);

 React.useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof document !== undefined) {
   document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyPressEventHandler, false);
  }
  return () => {
   if (typeof document !== undefined) {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyPressEventHandler, false);
   }
  };
 }, [onKeyPressEventHandler]);
 
 return (
  <div>
   HI
  </div>
 );

}
```

this opens a new window, but if I keep a `window.open('https://www.google.com/','_blank')` inside the use effect its works fine.

can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: The issue seems to be with how browser handle shiftKey + a link click. It basically opens the link in a new window (In Mac for sure). If you change that to altKey or ctrlKey then you have a solution. Not exactly the key combination you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `_blank` value for the `target` property, the common behaviour is to open the link in a new tab. But apparently the combination of the `_blank` value with the keys Shift + Enter force the opening of a new window (the same behaviour can be observed while focusing a link and pressing the two keys)

To avoid that, the easiest solution is to put the `window.open` method in a `setTimeout` like this :

```
setTimeout(() => window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank'));
```

It seems that if the call of the function is not synchronized with the event, the pressed keys won't changes the behaviour.